# How to find all the tables having column with CHAR Datatype and having numeric value in it?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to find all the tables which have columns with char data type but have numeric entry in it ,for instance if there is some table X with column `VALID_FLAG CHAR(1)` , then I have to check if this column has value 0 or 1 in it ?

I have no clue of this ,Please guide .

Comment: As a general comment, you shouldn't be using `char`. The standard string type is `varchar2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not achieve this using single query. You can write the PL/SQL procedure in oracle which will do the following:

> 1. Get the list of tables with columns where datatype is CHAR:

```
select table_name,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where data_type='CHAR'
and OWNER='OWNER_NAME';
```

> 2. Then you can put the check for 1 or 0:

```
select count(*) from table_name where column_name in ('1','0');
```

Comment: There is a column with a table name value in a ALL_TAB_COLUMNS so I do not see why user_tables is needed. Also `where column_name=1 or column_name=0;` is actualy 
 `where column_name in (0,1)`.  Comparing strings with numbers will give you an error so it should actualy be: `where column_name in ('0','1')`

Comment: Many thanks... you are right. I have updated the answer.

Comment: One more thing, your second step should be : `select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
from all_tab_columns
where data_type = 'CHAR'
and owner = 'YOUR_OWNER';` Because OP wants only columns with char data type and it would be great if he does not go through all the sys tables.

Comment: You have corrected one part not all: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=828d57721bbe033227cf279923c4a720

Comment: Ohhh... my bad.. now i am thinking why i was selecting list of tables first then checking data type...May be i could have noticed this while implementing.

Comment: Sir , can u please explain what view is table_name in last query ?

Comment: Output of first query that is `table_name,column_name and data_type` you can save in variable and then use the same in second query.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `xmlquery` and find the desired output in a single query as following:

```
WITH DATAA AS(select /*+ MATERIALIZE */ owner, table_name, column_name,
  to_number(xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
    passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
      'select count(1) as c '
      || 'from ' || table_name || ' WHERE ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' IN (''0'',''1'')'))
  returning content)) as c
from user_tab_columns
WHERE
    DATA_TYPE = 'CHAR')
SELECT * FROM DATAA
WHERE C > 0;
```

Cheers!!